# Bom dia, boa tarde ou boa noite?

Tags: ortografia, expressões, cumprimentos

Usamos as seguintes saudações:

> Bom dia, pela manhã, antes do meio-dia;
>   Boa tarde, após o meio-dia e antes das 18h;
>   Boa noite, após às 18h e antes da meia-noite.

Se bem que depois da meia-noite, quando ainda está escuro, é estranho dizer "bom dia".

Devemos seguir esses limites de horários?

Algumas vezes já vi e também usei, sem refletir sobre o assunto, mensagens de e-mail com saudação "bom dia", "boa tarde" ou "boa noite". Ora, se não sei quando o destinatário irá ler a mensagem, qual saudação devo usar?
É correto usar esse tipo de cumprimento em e-mail?

Comment: Bom dia é usado ou depois de acordar ou depois de o dia ficar claro (o sol nascer). Quando passa-se da meia-noite, continuamos com o uso do "boa noite" até umas 5hs da manhã, horário onde muitas pessoas acordam para trabalhar. O boa noite serve tanto para o cumprimento noturno quanto para desejar uma boa noite de sono. Sobre e-mail, comumente usamos de acordo com o horário em que o estamos escrevendo, e não com o que a pessoa lerá. O horário em que o e-mail é lido é, muitas vezes, imprevisível.

Comment: Já embarquei em avião algumas vezes de madrugada, tipo umas 2h da manhã e as comissárias de bordo me disseram "bom dia". Portanto acredito que formalmente falando deve-se dar "bom dia" após a meia noite, por mais que ainda não tenha raiado o sol. Acho que faz sentido pois elas não sabem se o passageiro já dormiu e acordou extremamente cedo para viajar ou se ele ainda nem dormiu.

Comment: @Math isso lembra a boa velha discussão do "boa tarde não, que eu ainda não almocei..."

Comment: Esse rigor é mais comum no inglês, nativos de inglês raramente saudam alguém com boa noite ou bom dia, depois das 23h59, apesar que alguns dizem que pela regra seria um estranho "bom dia". Por isso, preferem apenas um "Hi!". No Brasil, isso é muito flexível, mas destaco que enquanto o sol não surgir é "boa noite" e não "bom dia" (obviamente sem rigor: se a pessoa acorda às 3h e o sol ainda não nasceu é "bom dia").

Comment: Os franceses têm uma solução parcial para essas dúvidas: usam "bon jour" enquanto estiver claro,  pela manhã, a tarde e até às 20 horas se claro estiver.  Enquanto for dia, é "bon jour".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As fronteiras não são bem como as dizes:

- Podes dizer boa tarde até bem depois das 18h, especialmente durante o verão, quando o sol se põe pelas 21h (em Portugal). Mas mesmo durante o inverno, quando é de noite às 18h (a hora a que a maior parte das pessoas saem do trabalho), o mais comum será provavelmente dizer "boa tarde" até às 19h ou mesmo às 20h.
- A fronteira entre o "bom dia" e o "boa tarde" são de facto geralmente as 12h, mas há pessoas que usam o almoço como fronteira.
- Não se diz certamente "bom dia" depois da meia-noite; durante a madrugada diz-se "boa noite" se as pessoas não se tiverem deitado e "bom dia" se se tiverem levantado.

Em relação aos e-mails, é geralmente recomendado não usar este tipo de fórmulas, porque, mesmo que o destinatário esteja no mesmo fuso horário, é possível que só leia o e-mail muito tempo depois. O mais normal é começar os e-mails com "Caro X" (ou outras fórmulas informais ou semi-informais que se usam em cartas) ou mesmo omitir a fórmula completamente.

Comment: Este é um bom ponto: "durante a madrugada diz-se "boa noite" se as pessoas não se tiverem deitado e "bom dia" se se tiverem levantado."  Bem lembrado.

Comment: Nota de rodapé: se entendi bem a cultura local, acho que na Espanha o jantar também é fronteira do boa tarde/noite, às 21:30 ainda é razoável ir jantar. E lembrando que de 14 a 17h o comércio fecha. Dá pra escutar *Buenos Días* às 14h.

Comment: @brasofilo Em Portugal, também é razoável jantar às 21h30, mas nesse caso dificilmente estou a ver chegares a um restaurante e dizeres "boa tarde".

Comment: E eu utilizo bom dia para todo o dia, se for a primeira interação com a pessoa.

Comment: As fronteiras no Brasil é bem como descrito. Um exemplo entre Boa noite e Boa tarde. Ao chegar para um jantar com amigos, ainda antes de jantar, todos dirão: "Boa Noite".

Answer (score 6):

É difícil estabelecer limites precisos, principalmente em latitudes mais altas - acima de 50º norte ou sul, onde o amanhacer acontece antes das 4 horas no solsticio de verão e depois das 8 horas no de inverno.  Aqui na minha cidade estamos em "horário de verão" e só escurece por volta das 20 horas.  Entre 18 e 20 horas, cada um fica livre para dizer o que quiser.  Eu digo boa tarde quando ainda está claro, mas se alguém me desejar boa noite, é claro que eu respondo boa noite.

Quanto ao uso em e-mails, interpreto como se referindo a hora em que foi escrito. Mesmo assim, o cabeçalho da mensagem costuma trazer a hora (GMT) em que foi enviado.  Tenho visto, contudo, em noticiários pela TV, quando dois repórteres conversam ao vivo, o seguinte uso: Jorge está em Singapura (19h) e Sidney está no Rio de Janeiro (07h).  Jorge cumprimenta Sidney com "bom dia" e Sidney cumprimenta Jorga com "boa noite", cada um ciente das diferenças de fuso horário.

Answer (score 3):

Em e-mails é muito simples. Não use este tipo de saudação.

Existem dois tipos de comunicação. A síncrona, onde os interlocutores estão em comunicação direta e em tempo real e a assíncrona, onde os interlocutores não estão se comunicando no mesmo momento.

Exemplos do primeiro é a conversa pessoal, por telefone, chat, mensagem instantânea de vários tipos, *video-links*, rádio/tv, etc.

Exemplos do segundo são cartas, documentos, testes, livros e outras formas escritas em papel, placas/sinalizações, e-mails, fóruns, e outros sites onde a informação tem um caráter de persistência.

Em comunicação assíncrona não usa-se nada temporal justamente por não saber quando ele será lido. Tenho certeza que todos percebem que na maioria dos casos citados acima não cabe um "bom dia", "boa tarde", "boa noite". Se as pessoas sabiam como escrever uma carta e o e-mail é só uma carta transmitida por meio eletrônico, porque será que as pessoas desaprenderam como escrever?

Se não podemos estabelecer quando a pessoa vai ler (nem estou pensando em fuso horário), dizer um "bom dia" pode parecer educado, mas no fundo é um mecanicismo. É escrever algo só porque todo mundo faz isso. Não é um desejo genuíno.

Comment: Em 99% das vezes, falado ou escrito, "bom dia" **é** um mecanicismo.  Dizemos por sermos educados e não porque desejamos do fundo do coração que o ouvinte tenha um bom dia.

Comment: Essa definição do e-mail como necessariamente um meio assíncrono precisa ser bem relativizada. Assim como muitas vezes um aplicativo de "mensagem instantânea" é utilizado sabendo-se que o destinatário não pode ou não irá responder naquele momento (uso assíncrono), também muitas vezes se utiliza o e-mail quase como uma "mensagem instantânea", esperando-se a resposta imediata do interlocutor.

Answer (score 2):

Costumo dar bom dia em qualquer hora do dia, afinal o que tem 24hs? O dia certo. Então, acho chato desejar uma boa tarde por exemplo as 17:55 assim seriam apenas 10 bons minutos. Não é? Não sei se estou errada, mas me sinto bem assim.

Comment: Sou dessas também, e me sinto despeitada quando respondem meu 'Bom dia' com outro 'Bom' que não o 'dia'...-.-

Answer (score 1):

Na realidade devemos nos ater a acepção das palavras "dia" e "noite" nestas expressões. "Dia" refere-se do nascer ao pôr-do-sol e "noite" o inverso. Portanto, a expressão "bom dia" deve ser utilizada do nascer ao pôr-do-sol, enquanto "boa noite" do pôr-do-sol ao nascer do sol. Pode-se utilizar também "boa tarde" do meio-dia até o pôr-do-sol. Depois da meia-noite continua sendo "boa noite" já que não existe "boa madrugada".

Answer (score 1):

Sempre acho muito estranho quando o porteiro do meu prédio diz "Bom dia" durante a madrugada. Acho que o menos estranho (não necessariamente mais correto) é dizer bom dia ou boa tarde enquanto há claridade e boa noite quando não há. 
Do contrário fica um bocado estranho e vira um jogo de adivinhação. Aqui no Brasil é comum em um restaurante, durante o almoço, o atendente que te recepciona dizer bom dia, mas o do caixa (quando você já almoçou, portanto) diz boa tarde. Assim o que separa a manhã da tarde é a refeição, assim como o que separa o boa noite do bom dia é o ter dormido ou não. 
E acabo de lembrar que há uma meia dúzia de indivíduos que também separam o boa tarde do boa noite como antes e depois do jantar.
Vou continuar me atendo à luz do dia que é menos enlouquecedor.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que costumo ouvir o povo falar, entre meia-noite e seis da manhã (ou antes de amanhecer), usa-se tanto "Bom dia" quanto "Boa noite". Até o meio-dia, ou um tanto depois (por desatenção à hora), usa-se "Bom dia". Daí até as seis da tarde (ou até o anoitecer, por conta do horário de verão), usa-se "Boa tarde"; daí por diante, "Boa noite".

Por e-mail, não se usa nada disso; afinal, tal saudação não fará sentido para o destinatário, que pode ler o e-mail a qualquer momento, manhã, tarde ou noite.

Answer (score -1):

Mas se dizemos meio dia significa "Dia ainda". O mais correto deve se dizer após as 12h e 59 min boa tarde, por que se diz 13h (treze horas ou uma hora) da tarde , ou seja, primeiro horário da tarde que se estende até as 18h e 59 min, então a partir das 19h (ou sete) se diz boa noite! O modo mais correto de acompanhar as horas também.

Comment: Por favor, você poderia reescrever sua resposta com minúsculas? É visualmente desagradável para quem está lendo.